# Why does Android Firebase stop syncing until I re-login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

It looks like the Android Firebase stops syncing until I re-login.

- I push data to Firebase using the Firebase Admin SDK.
- I send an FCM message to the phone to wake it up. The message contains the new data's push ID. The Android app reads Firebase until it sees the new push ID and then processes the data.

Normally this works. Occasionally the phone gets in a state where it doesn't see the new push ID. Logging out/in causes it to start working again.

This is not a race condition because I send the push ID to the phone in the FCM message. That lets the Android app read until it sees the push ID (or time out sometimes in my case). I have verified that the data was pushed into Firebase and that the Android app is attempting to read the right ID.

Once the phone is in this state it continues to fail until I re-login. There are no errors or exceptions (the uid is not null, I can attach listeners). It just never sees the new push ID.  If I log out and log back in (without restarting the app) then it starts working again.  This is a very very intermittent problem.

A work around would be for me to store the credentials and re-login with a new auth token when the phone fails to read a known good push ID (btw, the app uses custom tokens generated by the Firebase Admin SDK)

Question: Am I missing something regarding authentication? Why does the Android app stop syncing until I re-login?

Comment: Same problem, any solution? this happen to me with only one app , the rest are working normally with firebase.